# Get last inserted auto_incrementID MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, insert, auto-increment

I try to get the last inserted auto_incremented ID after I execute a sqlstatement. I'm using the slim framework to do this. Here is my code:

```
$this->conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

...

$sql_stmt= "INSERT DELAYED INTO Tab(Id, Value1, Value2, Value3) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?)";

$stmt= $this->conn->prepare($sql_stmt);
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $param1, $param2, $param3);
$stmt->execute();
```

This is what I try to return the incremented value:

```
return mysqli_insert_id($this->conn);
return $this->conn->mysqli_insert_id();
return $this->conn->insert_id;
```

But this doesn't work...

Does anybody know how to get the value?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your using `INSERT DELAYED` so its probably not even been inserted by the time you are calling that code.

> When a client uses INSERT DELAYED, it gets an okay from the server at
>   once, and the row is queued to be inserted when the table is not in
>   use by any other thread.

and more specifically

> Because the INSERT DELAYED statement returns immediately, before the
>   rows are inserted, you cannot use LAST_INSERT_ID() to get the
>   AUTO_INCREMENT value that the statement might generate. from

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-delayed.html

So dont use delayed if you want to get the ID.